# How positron cannon works?

Tags: star-conflict

Usual behavior of positron cannon is that it shoots one per 1-1.5 second. And it is hard to say what exactly time interval to wait for 2nd shoot.

Though, I've noticed that sometimes it can should twice in a row with a quite small interval 0.25-0.5 seconds. But I could not realize how does that happen and how to make it shooting more frequently.

Also, I've noticed that positron cannon can accumulate up to two charges. It looks like if you press and keep pressed LMB for more than 1-1.5-2 seconds, shoot from the positron cannon is twice more powerful.

How to be sure when cannon is completely charged and can shoot with HIGHER power?

Any advises or information on this cannon is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not 100% sure, but I feel like the best power out positron cannon could be obtained if you keep LMB pressed immediately after click.

This way cannon starts accumulating charge and releases it (fires) the moment you release the button. If you keep the button long enough, cannon will accumulate more than 1 charge (now limit is 2) and when you have opportunity to shoot your damage will double (COOL STUFF! And imaging the critical shoot)

The drawback of this approach is weapon overheating, so you need to manage charge/break time and cooldown your weapon.